# Is there any way to test amp-list without a secure connection to the json?

Tags: amp-html

The AMP docs say that I need to populate the amp-list tag with json from a secure connection. My dev environment (linux in a vmware player) isn't a secure environment and I'm not server savvy enough to know what to do about that. Is there any way to get around this, for testing? Is there a way to give the amp-list straight json instead of getting it from a server?

Comment: Do you have Dropbox - that will work.

Comment: I tried putting a json file on my online server which does have https and got an error about my dev server not being secure so it wouldn't take the data. I'll just test it online; not having any luck getting a self signed cert working on my dev box.

Comment: You also need a CORS directory. Dropbox provides HTTPS and CORS.